# adding quantities to product-list.tpl in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I'm using the default theme in prestashop

I've found the place in products-list.tpl ( ~line 191 )where i want to add the code and want to show the stock level if it is less than 10

I've added

> {l s='Warning: remaining stock : '}{$product->quantity}

but  nothing numerical appears  with this code - I assume $product->quantity is empty. 
Is it a missing SQL query. and its not getting the attribute from the DB ?

Answer (score 1):

There `$product` is array, not an object, and in Smarty template you can have access to array element next way:

```
{l s='Warning: remaining stock : '}{$product.quantity}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks 
heres what I want to do 
(approx line 191 )

```
 {if $product.quantity <= 10}
 <span class="label-warning">{l s=' in stock : '}&nbsp{$product.quantity}</span> {else} 
<span> class="label-warning">{l s='in stock  : >10'}</span> {/if}
```